# "NLS missing message" Error for Eclipse while installing it

Tags: eclipse, windows-10-desktop

[image]

I downloaded the latest eclipse setup and tried to install it in my PC, but I get this error

```
NLS missing message: ECLIPSE_STARTUP_ERROR_CHECK_LOG in: org.eclipse.osgi.internal.messages.ExternalMessages
```

But when I used the same setup file in another PC, it got installed. Here both the PCs are installed with the same version of the Windows 10 and the Hardware is identical.

Now what am I missing here that I am unable to install it.

Before I posted this question I saw a lot of similar question related to the same error with Eclipse. But for those all problems the error occurred after installing the Eclipse while opening the workspace. Hence the solution given to them don't work much for me.

For me I get this error the moment I run the setup.

Comment: Download a package from https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/ if it's that urgent.

Comment: I downloaded a package and tried it. I got the same Error

Comment: *Which* package?

Comment: I downloaded the C/C++ Package

Comment: Did the original message you showed above happen when starting the installer, or while installing the C/C++ option?

Comment: It showed when starting the installer.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the previous eclipse folder. Open eclipse again. It will immediately work.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. I found that the zip was not correctly extracted. Try to unzip with any uncompressing software like 7zip

Comment: With any what? I dont know what you mean with that last sentance

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar issue , now im running my eclipse successfully ,
The Solution : just remove all occurences of eclipse from PC , then goto ninite.com
developer tools >>>>>>>> eclipse >>>>>>>>>>> download run the ninite_eclipse >>>>>> complete the installation
Now to good to go !